# Load all SRTM data into PostGIS

Tags: postgis, srtm, postgis-raster

I am trying to load all the SRTM data into a PostGIS database.  I tried the process described here: https://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html
It created a giant SQL file.  When I tried loading this file, the process used up all my machine's memory and crashed without loading anything.
How can I load all the SRTM data into a single PostGIS table?

Edit: Here is the command I used to create the SQL file:

```
raster2pgsql -c *.hgt srtm > srtm.sql
```

And then I loaded it with:

```
psql -d public -f srtm.sql
```

Edit: Here is the error I got:
...(many occurrences of the insert messages)...
INSERT 0 1
psql:srtm.sql:8520: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xd2 0xd2
psql:srtm.sql:8577: invalid command \
psql:srtm.sql:8604: invalid command \
psql:srtm.sql:9043: out of memory

Comment: I doubt a set of large files filled up *memory*, just disk storage. After generating the SQL, you're supposed to load it into the database, then archive or delete.

Comment: @Vince There is more than enough disk space.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use raster2pgsql instead of generating huge text files. On the tiff version (it should work with the other version too), I used it like that:

```
CREATE SCHEMA mnt;
raster2pgsql -d -C -I -M -t 200x200 -l 2,4,8 /data/*.tif public.mnt | PGPASSWORD=pass psql -h localhost -U your_user-w -d your_base
```

The `-l 2,4,8` is to create different aggregates to simplify the visualization in low level zoom, you can delete this part if you want. 
It worked for the whole world.

Comment: See my edit for the command I used to create the SQL file.

Comment: Yes, but I guess you should use it like I did to maybe avoid the problem (direct pipe instead of using a temporary sql file)